# Install Python Module in non-default Python Instance (Multiple Instance Installed)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have installed Python 3.8.5 and 3.7 on my computer. By default, it's 3.8.5. So anything that I pip installed is all for 3.8.5. However, I need to install some modules into 3.7 as well.

How can I install modules to that version?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you use any environment manager such as `virtualenv` or `conda`?

Comment: Which python distribution? If its anaconda, you may want to use its package manager.

Comment: No package manager, just the fresh install from the installer

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your terminal or anaconda prompt:

```
python3.7 -m pip install moduleOfYourChoice
```

Comment: The python 3.7 is not in the PATH. Python 3.8 is in the PATH now. So CMD doesn't recognize python3.7 command....